# Why does a capacitor plate connected to Earth lose charge?

Tags: capacitor, grounding, charge, electrostatic

Can you please explain this to me?
Is this correct? Why does the plate become neutral if the field outside the capacitor is zero?

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you are wondering why answer B is correct?

Comment: Who says the plate becomes neutral?

Comment: If we consider earth as reference (0 V) than it should become neutral (0 V) after connection. If answer b) is correct. Which I'm not sure...

Comment: Yes, I don't understand why charge flows through the switch.

Comment: Take away the first plate. You are left with a piece of metal with a charge +Q2. What happens when you connect it to earth? And what happens when you next bring the other piece with a charge +Q1 next to it?

Comment: Also, you can have a Plate at 0V but with net charge on it. I wouldn't call that neutral.

Comment: Physics question apart even *air* is slightly conductive so you should expect some gigaohm from *everything* toward earth. And in 99% of the cases earth is the reference so the leakage will put them at the same potential

Comment: I get the point about reference potential. So basically potentials of the plate and ground must be equal, but still don't understand why the charge through the switch is q1+q2.